# Mobile Website Version Error HTML,PHP website

Tags: css, html

My website [5focusmanagement.com](http://5focusmanagement.com) is not displaying completely on mobile. Only footer is displaying. May be error with HTML tags or CSS styling. Here I am attaching code. Please suggest me how can I display complete website when we open on mobile browsers. Thank you.

Please download the [code here..](http://5focusmanagement.com/indextest.txt)

Comment: Don't give us a link to the website, provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem. Links break, making your question turn into nonsense; Examples will always be useful to others once your question has been answered. Plus, giving us a link assumes we'll chase down the needed information necessary to help you, but instead they tend to discourage people who would answer you, so help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="container hidden-phone">`

You have a `hidden-phone` class that hides the content on mobile devices.

```
.hidden-phone {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Remove this rule and the content will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried same before but the images are overlapping with each other and website is not properly displaying. Can you please help me in displaying website with proper width, I mean fixed layout without overlapping of content.

Comment: Add a CSS rule for the body element with a `min-width` property.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but still problems with mobile version

Comment: Content and images are overlapping..please help me how to fix this?